# Where can I download VMWare Tools for 1.x?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-server, legacy, vmware-tools

Please can you show me where I can download the latest Version of VMWare Tools for the following Client:

- Server is Windows 2003 32 bit with VMWare Server 1.x (Yes, I know 1.x is old. We will upgrade later soon but not now.)
- Client is Windows 2003 32 bit

I could not find the installer on the vmware website. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in the vmware server console: vm - install vmware tools.

Then from inside the vm you will find a virtual cd-rom mounted with the installer files on it.